# @WebMvcTest for SOAP?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc, spring-boot-test

Is the Spring Boot annotation `@WebMvcTest` only intended for sliced `RestController` tests or should SOAP Endpoints be testable with it too?

When I setup my test and run it, I only get a 404 response as if the endpoint wasn't there so I assume it isn't part of the `WebMvc` slice.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = IdServerPortTypeV10.class)
@Import({SecurityConfig.class, ModelMapperConfig.class, WebServiceConfig.class, ControllerTestBeans.class})
public class AccountEndpointTests {
    @Autowired
    IdServerPortTypeV10 soapEndpoint;

    ...

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(wac)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = VALID_ROLE)
    public void getAccountTest_Success() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(
            post("/soap/idserver/1.0")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
                .headers(SoapTestUtility.getHeader(SERVICE.getNamespaceURI(), "getAccount"))
                .content(SoapTestUtility.getAccountXml())
        ).andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

The endpoint is enabled in `WebServiceConfig.class` in which `@EnableWs` is set.

Answer (score 0):

`@WebMvcTest` is, as the name implies, only for Spring MVC related tests.

Spring's SOAP support is from the Spring Web Services project which has its own integration testing support.